# React Page Not Scrolling

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a React JS web app. I have created few style sheets.

I have added a single Component to App.js but the window is not scrolling down to the contents of the added component.

I have tried `overflow-y: scroll;` to the html and body css class but it is not working. I want to scroll the entire page instead of single div component.

Here's the code for the component and the CSS on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/4v9fCeav).

Comment: Can you share your codes please?

Comment: Here is the code of both the components and CSS https://pastebin.com/4v9fCeav

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `auto` property instead of `scroll`.

Comment: there is no _default_ - I think you meant `overflow-y: auto;` -> see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp) for available options..